# it is not possible to upload a file to ftp via the Laravel 8 form

Tags: php, laravel, forms, file, ftp

I have a problem uploading a file in Laravel 8.81.0 on ftp.
I have this form in the home.blade.php file:

```
<form action="{{addFile}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
@method('PUT')
@csrf
<p>
<input type="file" name="profile_image" />
</p>
<button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>

</form>
```

I have yes in the controller

```
if($request->hasFile('profile_image')) {
    //get filename with extension
    $filenamewithextension = $request->file('profile_image')->getClientOriginalName();
    //get filename without extension
    $filename = pathinfo($filenamewithextension, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
    //get file extension
    $extension = $request->file('profile_image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
    //filename to store
    $filenametostore = $filename.'_'.uniqid().'.'.$extension;
    //Upload File to external server
    Storage::disk('ftp')->put($filenametostore, fopen($request->file('profile_image'), 'r+'));
    //Store $filenametostore in the database
}
```

in the .env file I added

```
FTP_HOST=xxx 
FTP_USERNAME=xxx
FTP_PASSWORD=xxx
```

In the filesystems.php file

```
'disks' => [
    'ftp' => [
        'driver' => 'ftp',
        'host' =>  env(xxx),
        'username' =>  env(xxx),
        'password' =>  env('xxx'),
        'root' => '/public/' // for example: /var/www/html/dev/images
    ],
```

But anyway after uploading the file I get the error: ValueError
Path cannot be empty.

I am using file transfer for the first time, so I would be grateful for a hint of what I am doing wrong
I mention that directories are set to allow file writing

Answer (score 0):

```
'ftp' => [
            'driver' => 'ftp',
            'host' => 'FTP_HOST',
            'username' => 'FTP_USERNAME',
            'password' => 'FTP_PASSWORD',
            'passive' => 'false', 
            'ignorePassiveAddress' => true,
            'port' => 21,
            'root' => 'public_html/storage/app/public/Your_Folder/' // for example: /public_html/images
        ]
//file will save in storage directory you need to link storage for access your files

$path = $file->store('Your Folder','ftp');
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).